# Return NULL if date is not exists in right side table using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables
table 1: M1

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
propertyId                              productId
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
041E09A8-BB30-4555-91AC-E366AFD4DD79    B20D2D1E-C6D2-4821-B58D-B031E737B732
E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1    B20D2D1E-C6D2-4821-B58D-B031E737B732
```

table 2: M2

```
------------------------------------------------------------
propertyId                             startdate    volume
------------------------------------------------------------
041E09A8-BB30-4555-91AC-E366AFD4DD79    2019-06-20     5
E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1    2019-06-20    10
041E09A8-BB30-4555-91AC-E366AFD4DD79    2019-06-21    15
```

Expected out put should be like (even if the 'propertyid' not exists for the period should return empty)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
propertyId                             startdate    volume
--------------------------------------------------------------------
041E09A8-BB30-4555-91AC-E366AFD4DD79    2019-06-20      5
E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1    2019-06-20     10
041E09A8-BB30-4555-91AC-E366AFD4DD79    2019-06-21     15
E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1    NULL           NULL
```

here propertyid 'E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1' dont have the record for date '2019-06-21'.
Could you please help me ?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). And note that '9AF7', say is simpler for us humans to comprehend than, say 'E46F20AC-9AF7-43BB-AC06-79BF61C8E8B1' - without losing any of the meaning of the question.

Comment: Why would you "fabricate" a row for <EF...> for a date of June 21 2019 but not include that date in the "fabricated" row? And what should happen if there where more dates and more "missing" rows?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select m1.propertyid, d.startdate, m2.volume
from m1 cross join
     (select distinct startdate from m2) d left join
     m2
     on m2.startdate = d.startdate and m2.propertyid = m1.propertyid
```